# Design problems: Reservation system

Tags: java

I have to design and implement a reservation system for a hotel. I have

- an array list of Reservation objects
- an array list of room objects

I want to 'reserve' the room at a given date.

To book a room without a date would be easy but its the date part that's complicating it. I'm struggling with the design of this and confident with a nudge in the right direction I could code it.

How do you say that a room is booked at this date but not at that date?

There is no database or anything its just an abstracted reservation system.

(I've been staring at this for a while, forgive me if if the solution is easy)

Thanks.

Comment: If this is a homework, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: I think you should also find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008495/decoupling-mysql-data-versus-ease-of-use/8009992#8009992

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT -- on second thought, why not just let each `Room` have a list of `Reservation` instances, which in turn have start/end properties that tell you when the reservation occurs?

That way, to tell if a room has a reservation for a certain time, you just loop thru the reservations for the room and see if the time in question is within the start/end range of any of the reservations...granted that code is not too easy (nor too hard) to implement, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Ah that's a brilliant idea. I was thinking a new class or something, but a room that stores when its reserved as well as the other data like its price and so on is a great idea.

EDIT: I love this website. I didn't have to explicitly ask for code or anything and can still feel good about my self when I code the solution, that I was hinted in the right direction instead of told.

Comment: @shane, cool -- just be aware that searching for an open reservation can be tricky with this structure -- you need to search potentially every room to find an open spot.

Answer (score 10):

Create three classes (`Hotel`, `Room` & `Reservation`) :

- `Reservation` object is used like an invoice here, and is kept *decoupled* from booking process.
- Each `Room` object (dedicated for each room number in the hotel) contains a `map` which stores `reservedDates` as key and `reservationObject` as value.
- `Hotel` composes of `rooms`. For each booking request, `Hotel` loops through the `room` list, and with that, each `room` traverse through its own `map` to find if the booking is possible for *asked* days.

Note that the booking function is taking dates as list, not just two dates (as startDate and endDate). It's same thing as the former can be derived from the later.

Sample Code is as below:

```
class Hotel {
    private String name, address;
    private List<Room> roomList;   //key : roomNumber
    public Hotel(){
        roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
    }
    public Reservation bookRoomForDates(List<Integer> dateList, Guest guest){
        for(Room room : roomList){
            Reservation reservation = room.bookForGivenDates(dateList, guest);
            if(reserved != null) return reservation; //Reservation successFull!
        }
        return null; //Reservation failed!
    }
}
class Reservation {
    private String id;
    private Date inDate, outDate;
    private Guest guest;

    public Reservation(Room room, int startDate, int endDate, Guest guest){
        //populate the member variables.
    }
}

class Room {
    private String id;
    private int roomNumber, floorNum;
    private Map<Integer, Reservation> reservedDates;  // key : date as Integer (YYYYMMDD)

    public Room(int roomNumber){
        reservedDates = new HashMap<Integer, Reservation>();
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    }

    //A guest request for booking on dates(in YYYYMMDD format) in the dateList
    public Reservation bookForGivenDates(List<Integer> dateList, Guest guest)  
    {   
        if(dateList.isEmpty()) return null;

        for(Integer date : dateList){
            Reservation res = reservedDates.get(date);  
            if(res != null) {  // We don't store null value for unreserved dates for the room.
                return null;  // Room is reserved on this date by another guest. So, this room is unavailable.
            }
        }
        //this room is unreserved on all requested dates. So go on and reserve this room for asked dates
        int startDate = dateList.get(0);
        int endDate   = dateList.get(dateList.size() - 1);

        Reservation newReservation = new Reservation(this, startDate, endDate, guest);
        for(Integer date : dateList){
            reservedDates.put(date, newReservation);
        }
        return newReservation;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it Saurav but this question is almost 5 years old (from my student days) so I no longer need help considering I have graduated now :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about it, *Room* is a resource that you can *reserve* for a given time range. Also you have several rooms which can be reserved independently. How would you implement the following methods:

```
class Room {
  boolean isAvailable(Date date) {/*...*/}
  Date nextAvailableDate() {/*...*/}
}
```

Hint: *room has to know about its reservations*.

It's not clear from your question what is the purpose of *Reservation*. Does it only contain a date range or is it assigned to a particular room? If the former, you might encounter a problem of finding a free room for a new reservations - this can be easily implemented by looping over all rooms and using methods above.

If the latter: since the reservations knows about the room, the room may also know about the reservation. So implementing the methods above is trivial by iterating over reservations.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final_Project {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner ScanObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice="";
            int a=1;
            int x;
            int stay=0;
             int totalBill;
            String name="";
            String num="";
    String checkIn="";
            String checkOut="";

    System.out.println("Kindly Fillup");

            Date d = new Date();




    System.out.print("Name:");
    name = ScanObj.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Phone Number:");
    num =ScanObj.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Check-in: ");
            checkIn = ScanObj.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Check-Out: ");
            checkOut = ScanObj.nextLine();



    System.out.println("Hello," + name + ". Welcome to Kimberly Hotel");
do{ 
    try{

    for(x=1; x==1;) {

        System.out.println("[1] Room Reservations");

    for(x=1; x==1;) {

        System.out.print("ENTER : ");
        choice=ScanObj.nextLine();

            if (choice.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("            Rooms");
                System.out.println("*********************************");
                System.out.println("1.)Room 101   | Php 10,000 |5 Persons");
                System.out.println("2.)Room 102   | Php 8,000 |4 Persons");
                System.out.println("3.)Room 103   | Php 6,500 |3 Persons");
                System.out.println("4.)Room 104   | Php 5,000 |2 Persons");
                System.out.println("5.)Room 105   | Php 5,000 |2 Persons");
                x=0;

            }

            else
                throw new InputMismatchException("");
                a=2;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");

        }

}while(a==1);

int choices;
int control=1;
do{

    try{

        System.out.print("Please select a room: ");
        choices = ScanObj.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("How long will you stay: ");
                    stay = ScanObj.nextInt();



        switch(choices) 
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Here is your reservation as of: " + d.toString());
            System.out.println(name+" |"+num+"|1 Room 101 | Php 10,000 | 5 Persons|");
                            System.out.println("Check-in Date: " + checkIn);
                            System.out.println("Check-Out Date: " + checkOut);
                            totalBill = stay * 10000;
                            System.out.println("Your total bill is: " + totalBill);
                            System.out.println("Additional 2 beddings");
                            System.out.println("Free Breakfast");
                            System.out.println("No pets allowed!");
                            System.out.println("Thank You!");
            break;
        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Here is your reservation as of: " + d.toString());
            System.out.println("Here is your reservation: ");
            System.out.println(name+" |"+num+"| Room 102  | Php 8,000 | 4 Persons|");
                            System.out.println("Check-in Date: " + checkIn);
                            System.out.println("Check-Out Date: " + checkOut);
                            totalBill = stay * 8000;
                            System.out.println("Your total bill is: " + totalBill);
                            System.out.println("Additional 2 beddings");
                            System.out.println("Free Breakfast");
                            System.out.println("No pets allowed!");
            System.out.println("Thank You!");
                            break;
        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Here is your reservation as of: " + d.toString());
            System.out.println("Here is your reservation: ");
            System.out.println(name+" |"+num+"| Room 103  | Php 6,500 | 3 Persons|");
                            System.out.println("Check-in Date: " + checkIn);
                            System.out.println("Check-Out Date: " + checkOut);
                            totalBill = stay * 8000;
                            System.out.println("Your total bill is: " + totalBill);
                            System.out.println("Additional 2 beddings");
                            System.out.println("Free Breakfast");
                            System.out.println("No pets allowed!");
                            System.out.println("Thank You!");
            break;
        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Here is your reservation as of: " + d.toString());
            System.out.println("Here is your reservation: ");
            System.out.println(name+" |"+num+"| Room 104  | Php 5,000 | 2 Persons|");
                            System.out.println("Check-in Date: " + checkIn);
                            System.out.println("Check-Out Date: " + checkOut);
                            totalBill = stay * 8000;
                            System.out.println("Your total bill is: " + totalBill);
                            System.out.println("Additional 1 beddings");
                            System.out.println("Free Breakfast");
                            System.out.println("No pets allowed!");
                            System.out.println("Thank You!");
            break;
        case 5:
                            System.out.println("Here is your reservation as of: " + d.toString());
            System.out.println("Here is your reservation: ");
            System.out.println(name+" |"+num+"| Room 105  | Php 5,000 | 2 Persons|");
                            System.out.println("Check-in Date: " + checkIn);
                            System.out.println("Check-Out Date: " + checkOut);

                            System.out.println("Additional 1 beddings");
                            System.out.println("Free Breakfast");
                            System.out.println("No pets allowed!");
                            System.out.println("Thank You!");
            break;

        default:
        System.out.println("Number"+" "+choices + " is not given. Please select within the given rooms.");
        throw new InputMismatchException("");

        }
        control=2;

    }catch(InputMismatchException ex) {

    }


}while(control==1);

        System.out.println("");
        int choicess;
        boolean b=true;
    do{
        try{

                System.out.println("[1] CANCEL");
                System.out.println("[2] RESERVE");


        System.out.println("Select from above: ");  
        choicess=ScanObj.nextInt();

        switch(choicess)    
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Cancellation Done Thanks!");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Your hotel room has been successfully reserved. Thank you!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error. Please select within the given numbers.");
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
            throw new InputMismatchException("");

        }
        b=false;

    }catch(Exception exx) {

        System.out.println("");


    }

    }while(b!=false);

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When answering a question, it is helpful to include a brief explanation of your code, or add descriptive comments to the relevant part of the code, rather than just posting a large block of code.